# Apache mod_reqtimeout not dropping long requests

Tags: security, apache

In order to protect ourselves from a slowloris-type attack, we have configured the mod_reqtimeout module on our Apache 2.2.17 installation (running on Solaris, MPM compiled).  The mod_reqtimeout is configured as follows:

RequestReadTimeout header=10-20,MinRate=500 body=10-20,MinRate=500

We are testing using the OWASP http_dos_cli tool and are still able to make the site unreachable in a couple of seconds.  In the logs we see that the request is truncated after 20 seconds and is then processed. Since the URL is referring to an actual resource, a 200 status code is returned. This prevents our mod_security rule set to detect 408 status codes, gather IP-based statistics and block further requests from this IP.

Any idea on why mod_reqtimeout is truncating the request instead of dropping it and returning a 408?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Actually, Apache is sending a 302 Redirect because of a RedirectMatch directive in the httpd-vhosts.conf file.  Still, that request should time out and return a 408, not a 302.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have opened a bug report and received confirmation that issues in HTTPD Core are causing the following problems:

- Apache doesn't always return a 408 when a request time out is detected (various cases)
- Apache doesn't handle a request time out properly when the URL corresponds to a RedirectMatch directive

More details here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51103

Hope that helps someone eventually.